# eclipse associate a dynamic web app with tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I followed the instruction [on this page](http://www.java2blog.com/2015/09/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-using.html) to create a simple maven web app:

However, when on step 11: Right click on project -> run as -> run on server, there is no "tomcat" and i got an error message: the selection did not contain any resources that can run on a server.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvU87.jpg)

Also as the picture shown, I have successfully added tomcat in servers view and the app is also shown in the server list unfer tomcat 8.0. In the property->runtimes window, tomcat is in the list and checked. but 'make it primary" is disabled and in the "runtime composition" panel the message is `<no runtime selected>`.

localhost:8080/mavenWebApp got 404 error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is `Make Primary` disabled when you select `Tomcat` from the list? Nothing's selected in http://i.stack.imgur.com/KvU87.jpg .

Comment: Thanks, selected tamcat 8.0, i can see in the lower left panel now, but "Make Primary" is still disabled. Right click on project -> run as -> run on server, there is no "tomcat" and still got error message: the selection did not contain any resources that can run on a server.

Comment: the war file is generated successfully under target after build. localhost.8080 showed welcome page but localhost:8080/mavenWebApp got 404 error.